# Javascript change button text by value

Tags: javascript, html, button

Maybe I'm not googling right but I have a simple question that I was not able to find an answer. I have a group of buttons with specific text. Because the page is dynamic depending on the user choices there may be five buttons cut for example.

```html
<button>Cut</button>
<button>Copy</button>
<button>Speak</button>
<button>Fullscreen</button>
```

Above you can see one group but there might be the same buttons copied 10 times. I want to change the text of those buttons by getting their value. For example:

Getting all buttons with text `"Cut"` and change their value to `"foo"`

Then I want to do something similar with other text to the other buttons. How to do that?

Comment: so what you tried?

Comment: Why can't you just do a find and replace in your source code?

Comment: Because as I said the page is dynamic and is depending on the user how many buttons will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all the buttons and iterate through them using `forEach` loop. Check their text using `textContent` and if it is **Cut** set it to **foo**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((e)=>e.textContent=='Cut'?e.textContent="foo":false)
```

```html
<button>Cut</button>
<button>Copy</button>
<button>Cut</button>
<button>Speak</button>
<button>Cut</button>
<button>Fullscreen</button>
<button>Cut</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I really appreciate that your solution is the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting all the buttons using `document.getElementsByTagName()` and filtering based on the content. Then you can iterate over your filtered array and perform whatever modifications you want:

```
// get all buttons as an array
const buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button"));

// filter the array using a strict string equality check
const cutButtons = buttons.filter(button => button.textContent === "Cut");

// perform your modifications
cutButtons.forEach(button => {
   button.textContent = "foo";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the buttons. Then loop through them to check the *textContent* to modify the button:

```js
var btn = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'));

btn.forEach(function(b){
  if(b.textContent == 'Cut')
    b.textContent = 'foo';
});
```

```html
<button>Cut</button>
<button>Copy</button>
<button>Speak</button>
<button>Fullscreen</button>
<button>Cut</button>
```

Comment: why you need `[].slice.call`

Comment: but why you want to convert `document.querySelectorAll('button')` into array?

Comment: @brk, as far as I know `forEach()` does not work with `querySelectorAll()` in some version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Get buttons by tag name using getElementsByTagName() then with in for loop check content and change it if "Cut" using Node.textContent

```
var cut=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<cut.length;i++){
        if(cut[i].textContent=="cut"){
            cut[i].textContent="foo"
    }
}
```